# How to automatically scale and align /tikzpicture with font size

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, scaling

I've created some symbols with TikZ (and for some of them used `shapes.geometric`) to use within text, e. g. this one:

```
\newcommand{\kttriangle}{\tikz{\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, draw, fill=black] at (0,0) {};}}
```

However, it was too big so I scaled it down:

```
\newcommand{\kttriangle}{\tikz{\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, draw, fill=black, scale=0.55] at (0,0) {};}}
```

The vertical alignment of the scaled version didn't look good, so I adjusted that too:

```
\newcommand{\kttriangle}{\tikz[baseline=-2.5]{\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, draw, fill=black, scale=0.55] at (0,0) {};}}
```

[image: TikZ icon]

Now it finally looks as intended, but the whole process is rather tedious and has to be repeated for every font size and new icon. Therefore, I'd really like to know if it's possible to

- automatically scale the tikzpicture to the surrounding font size
- automatically adjust the baseline / vertical alignment to the surrounding font
  ?

Comment: One idea would be not to use a node but really draw this triangle using em as unit which scales with the font.

Comment: Don't use `scale` to change the node's size but `minimum size` (describing the circumference) or `ìnner sep` (describing the incircle). Here you can use font units as well (`ex` and `em`). Though, for a simple triangle, you don't really need a node as @JasperHabicht shows in their answer.

Comment: Thanks! I know that the triangle is easy to draw manually, but I also need more complex icons (e. g. an equilateral pentagon), which are easier to do with `shapes.geometric`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion is not to use a node shape to draw such a simple symbol, because Ti*k*Z nodes don't scale with the coordinate system in any case.

Instead, I'd just draw the triangle using coordinates with em as unit which is a unit that scales with the font size:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\kttriangle}{%
    \tikz{
        \fill (0:0em) -- (0:0.8em) -- (60:0.8em) -- cycle;
    }%
}

\begin{document}

{ \Huge Foo \kttriangle{} bar }

{ Foo \kttriangle{} bar }

{ \footnotesize Foo \kttriangle{} bar }

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want to use nodes, you can use the same logic. You need to make sure that the node shape is exactly 1em (or some other value with em as unit) high. So you should set its `inner sep` to 0pt and its `minimum height` to 1em.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\newcommand{\kttriangle}{%
    \tikz{
        \node[fill, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, 
            minimum height=0.9em, inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {};
    }%
}

\begin{document}

{ \Huge Foo \kttriangle{} bar }

{ Foo \kttriangle{} bar }

{ \footnotesize Foo \kttriangle{} bar }

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Finally, although I don't suggest doing this, you *can* use the `scale` option, but for this to work, you need to calculate the factor for scaling. You could do this by dividing the current length of 1em by 1cm (which is the default unit in Ti*k*Z).

But note that scaling a Ti*k*Z environment only scales the coordinate system. If you need to also scale nodes and/or line widths etc. you need to additionally use the options `transform shape` or `transform canvas`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\emunit}
\newcommand{\kticon}{%
    \setlength{\emunit}{1em}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ktscale}{\the\emunit/1cm}%
    \tikz[scale={\ktscale}]{
        \draw[fill] (0,0) rectangle (0.8,0.8);
    }%
}

\begin{document}

{ \Huge Foo \kticon{} bar }

{ Foo \kticon{} bar }

{ \footnotesize Foo \kticon{} bar }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, great solutions for the scaling! Thanks a lot @jasper-habicht! Do you also have an idea about the vertical alignment? Basically I need the icons to be centered to the line of text. By default they are "bottom-aligned", which looks OK for a triangle, but very bad for sth. like crosshairs (they are placed too high):
```
\tikz{\draw[thick] (-0.5em,0) -- (0.5em,0) (0,-0.5em) -- (0,0.5em) (0,0) circle radius=0.3em];}
```
Your scaling solution gave me the idea to use `[baseline=-0.3em]` (instead of `-3pt`, which only works for a 10pt font), but maybe there's a better solution?

Comment: @seeplusn00b I guess if you use nodes, you can add `yshift=0.1em` or similar to it. Would this work?

Comment: For some reason, setting `yshift=` doesn't have any effect (tried as node and `\tikz` command option). Anyway, `baseline` works fine for now and it also scales with the font size when using `em`. I was just curious if there's another well-known / more robust solution for my alignment issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @seeplusn00b Sorry, you are right, `baseline` is the way to go, as we are in an inline context here. Anyways, the key is to use em as unit.